# C++ If- with types in a template

Tags: c++

I have a class template and I want to do something when the type is an integer, and do something else when it's a string and double. How can I do it? I've got a method like this:

```
template <typename T> class abc{
    void method(T i)
    {
        if(i is a string)
          do sth
        else if(i is an integer)
          do sth else
        else if(i is a double)
          do sth else else
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems more like you need *overloading* than templates. Or possibly template specialization.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to do a list, and I can compare a>b when it comes to integer and double, but I'm not able to do it with strings

Comment: if each type needs its own seperate implementation that have nothing in common, there is little point in making the method a template. Just use overloads

Comment: why are you not able to do it with strings? afaik strings have an `operator<`

Comment: btw in case you want to do something and it doesnt work you better ask for that thing and show the code that doesnt work, instead of asking about a solution (that also doesnt work).

Comment: `std::string`, `int` and `double` all have a comparison operator, you don't need to check what type the variables are. Just do e.g. `a < b` where `a` and `b` are both variables using a template argument.

Comment: sorry, I got used to java, in which i can't do it, now the problem is gone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use template specialization.

```
template<typename T>
class A {
    void method(T);
};
```

And you define a specialization for the type you want

```
template<> void A<int>::method(int) {}
template<> void A<string>::method(string) {}
template<> void A<float>::method(float) {}
```

I didn't test this code but you can find more information here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization

Answer (score 1):

> I want to do a list, and I can compare `a > b` when it comes to integer and double, but I'm not able to do it with strings – [jakub1998](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44302905/c-if-with-types-in-a-template#comment75611447_44302905)

As a matter of fact, you can compare strings. But in the general case, you can mimic what [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) does, and take in a second template parameter that is a policy for ordering two `T`s:

```
template <typename T, typename Compare = std::greater<T>>
class abc {
    void method(T i, T j)
    {
        if(Compare{}(i, j)) {
            // ...
        }
    }
};
```

Note the default argument [`std::greater`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater), which falls back to calling `i > j` if the user doesn't provide a custom comparator.

Answer (score 0):

```
template <typename T>
void method(T i){
if(typeid(i) == typeid(string)){
cout << "string" <<endl;
}else if(typeid(i) == typeid(int)){
 cout << "int" <<endl;
}else{
///...
 }
}

int main() {

string a = "";
method(a);
return 0;
```

}

and you should include :

```
#include <typeinfo>
```

Comment: code only answers arent nice, badly formatted code only answers are worse. On top of that this wont help